# Is it possible to define WSDL for a port listener?

Tags: java, tcp, wsdl

I have a TCP-IP port listening implementation that basically receives an xml and sends an xml. Is it possible to define a wsdl for this service without altering the implementation?

Comment: Web services work over HTTP, so unless you made your own implementation of HTTP in your socket server, I don't think you can expose it as a web service.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, after the client connected it sends the defined xml byte-by-byte. There is nothing else. So this means I need to create a web service on another port to expose the function as a web service?